# Objective-C: Create custom UIPopoverController like in iCalendar App

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Is it possible to create a custom UIPopoverController? Can you give me some suggestions (Links, tutorial...)?

I would create a sort of popover like the one in **iPad** calendar application. When the popover appears (in view mode), it has no border (white background). Then, when you enter the modify mode (for example through a modify button), the popover chage its appereance (the border color and so on).

Thank you in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested in.

See [cmpoptipview-custom-popup-view-for-ios](http://blog.chrismiles.info/2010/12/cmpoptipview-custom-popup-view-for-ios.html) if you need to create custom popover in iOS.

Since iOS5 it is also possible to customize the background view for the popover. For further info see **Customizing the Popover Appearance** section in [UIPopoverController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The only way seems to be creating a new pop over view (custom) and adding it as a subview .

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows a very very basic tutorial on custom popover controllers...
http://blog.blackwhale.at/2010/04/show-a-custom-popover-view/
hope this gives you a good start...

Comment: Thank you learner2010. The link you provided seems to talk about the internal view customization of a popup controller. I'm looking for changing the style of a popup itself...

Comment: ok.. when i come across that, I will post a link here.. suppose you find what you are looking for, it would be great if you could post it...

Comment: Hi, I've found this link. Maybe It could be useful [link](http://chrismiles-tech.blogspot.com/2010/12/cmpoptipview-custom-popup-view-for-ios.html)